# Why do simple optical fibers usually support only half-duplex communication?

Tags: electromagnetism, communication, cables, optics, optical-fibre

I'm a newbie to the subject, so a thorough answer would be very helpful.
I was curious as to why simple (single) optical fibers usually don't allow full-duplex communication. To my understanding, all basic optical fiber configurations support only half-duplex communication.

As I tried to find an answer to this question, I found out that there are many ways of multiplexing rx/tx in parallel on the same fiber (e.g. [Wavelength-division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength-division_multiplexing) and [Time-division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing)). But to my surprise, the only solution I found for a fully-parallel communication with a single wavelength is a relatively new technology from CableLabs, namely [Direction-division multiplexing](https://www.cablelabs.com/technologies/full-duplex-coherent-optics).

So my questions are:

1. Why can't simple optical communication systems transmit and receive light of a single wavelength in parallel?
2. Why doesn't the same problem occur when using multiple wavelengths (e.g. in *Wavelength-division multiplexing*)?
3. How does *Direction-division multiplexing* solve that problem?

The answers to ["Are optical fibers full duplex?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42268/253304) don't satisfy my questions above. One [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/204797/253304) mentions "reflections" as a problem preventing full duplex, but it is missing a more in-depth physical explanation and some credible sources.

Comment: How much are you emphasizing "simple"? Because the answer could simply be, it's more complicated to do full-dupex than half-duplex. With regards to reflections, it could be that the transmitted beam reflects off the far end and comes back which causes self-interference (beats). Some types of sensors rely on this. Or the incoming beam could cause interference with the outgoing beam.

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't simple optical communication systems transmit and receive light of a single wavelength in parallel?

Because it's difficult to isolate the receiver from the transmitter, and the transmitter on the near side will overwhelm the receiver, so it won't be able to see the transmitted light from the far side.

> Why doesn't the same problem occur when using multiple wavelengths (e.g. in Wavelength-division multiplexing)?

Because you can easily filter out the transmitted light while allowing the received light, using a wavelength-selective (i.e. colored) filter.

> How does Direction-division multiplexing solve that problem?

Someone has invented a duplexer that only lets light through if it's passing in one direction, and not the other.  This is probably the optical analog of a SWR coupler for microwaves -- but I'm guessing.

They did a good enough job of it that the transmitted light *doesn't* overwhelm the receiver, and there you go.

I would not be at all surprised if, when you dig into it, you'll find in the small print that the range is limited, because the duplexer lets *some* outgoing light back into the receiver, and so the light received from the far end has to be stronger than otherwise.  But -- I could be wrong; I'm just cynical.

Comment: "a duplexer that only lets light through if it's passing in one direction, and not the other" is called a circulator and they've been commercially available for decades.

Comment: Please edit my answer then -- my formal education in optics barely encompasses burning up ants on a sunny day.

Comment: @user1850479 I wouldn't call circulator simple though. At least not cheap. Took me forever to find out what that missing link was that let people do laser interferometry and it was called a circulator because  no one seems to talk about them.

Comment: @TimWescott I skimmed that webpage and addressed it in my answer.

Comment: @DKNguyen Laser interferometry uses beam splitters rather than circulators (since light passes through a circulator without interfering, which is not what you want in an interferometer).  Circulators are sometimes used before/after fiber-based interferometers though for getting the light into or out of the interferometer without having to go to free space.

Comment: @user1850479 Yeah, the fiber types were the ones I was investigating at the time since it space-limited. Ones that use an integrated laser diode and photodiode for self-interference rather than the kind that uses prisms to split beams. It was a mystery component in all the block diagrams but very few actually named it.

Comment: So you're saying the reflections from the transmitter on the near side would overpower the transmissions from the far side. But how does the "duplexer that only lets light through if it's passing in one direction, and not the other" help with that? Wouldn't such a thing just make the fiber uni-directional?

Answer (score 1):

Fiber is so cheap it's common to bury lots more than you need and just leave it for the future. Conversely receivers are not cheap, so you don't want to add unnecessary complexity if you don't have to.  Since the goal is to send as many bits per second for the lowest cost, you typically just use more fiber, especially for "simple" systems.

To answer your specific questions:

**Why can't simple optical communication systems transmit and receive light of a single wavelength in parallel?**

They can, but why would you?  What problem would that solve?  Fiber is very, very cheap, and if you can't use two fibers, then crude forms of WDM are very cost effective.

**Why doesn't the same problem occur when using multiple wavelengths (e.g. in Wavelength-division multiplexing)?**

You are really asking why WDM is cheaper. For "simple" systems like these 10gbit SFP+ transmitters, adding WDM as opposed to using two fibers increases the retail cost by $1.00:

https://www.fs.com/products/42306.html

WDM can be that cheap because the multiplexing in this case is performed using lasers with widely spaced wavelengths, so simple color filters can be used. These are very cheap (cents) and cheap is what matters.

Conversely, to use the same wavelength, you need a circulator to sort light by direction.  These require first that the light be polarized (or else you need two circulators), and further require magneto-optical materials and strong magnetic fields.  Polarization is expensive.  Magnetics are expensive.  Color filters are not.

**How does Direction-division multiplexing solve that problem?**

I've never heard of that before, but the webpage you linked more or less provides the seller's answer to this question.  They describe a system for low cost ISP networks where the ISP has a single laser on their end.  The user doesn't have a laser, just a circulator, which they use to extract the laser beam, read any signals on it, then apply their modulation, and then send back modulated beam.  The cost savings is that the user has no laser and is just modulating the ISP's signal back to them.  Note that since there is just one laser, you are still limited to only one end talking at a time.

Allegedly this is supposed to be cheaper because there are fewer lasers, but lasers are not expensive.  Presumably the vendor has some trick to make the circulator cheaper. Possibly with enough power the "circulator" could actually just be a beam splitter, which could be very cheap (and very lossy).

**One answer mentions "reflections" as a problem preventing full duplex, but it is missing a more in-depth physical explanation and some credible sources.**

This heavily depends on the situation.  If this is a fixed fiber link, and I'm fusion splicing the fiber, I can get the reflection down to a tiny fraction of a percent.   Further, if you have a coherent receiver (like the Direction-division multiplexing scheme you linked above), the reflections don't matter anyway since they're not coherent with the receiver and are not detected.

Conversely, if this is an ethernet fiber going under someone's desk using incoherent detection, and they're not polishing and cleaning it after each insertion, then their finger print on the fiber face might mean a quarter of the laser power is bouncing back into the receiver.  That would be a problem.